# SQL Delete Rows Based on Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, sql-delete, delete-row

I have a table with eight columns including a device ID, a device reading type, and a device reading date. Those three columns would look like this:
[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhMQX.jpg)

What I would like to do is delete every row for which DevReadType = XX and every row with a matching DevNum but a DevReadDate that is less than the date when DevReadType = 'XX'. I haven't been able to find any examples with this kind of complex conditional. Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: what is your rdbms? Show us sample data and expected result.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I would suggest something along the lines of:

```
DELETE  d
FROM device d
JOIN (
    SELECT DevNum, MAX(DevReadDate) maxDevReadDate
    FROM device
    WHERE devReadType = 'xx'
    GROUP BY DevNum
) b
ON d.DevNum = b.DevNum AND (d.DevReadDate < b.maxDevReadDate OR d.devReadType = 'xx')
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from device
   where  DevNum = @devicenum
   and    DevReadType = 'XX'
   and    DevReadDate < @date
```

you can test your where clause by running the select againsr the device table first:

```
select * 
from device
    where  DevNum = @devicenum
    and    DevReadType = 'XX'
    and    DevReadDate < @date
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Max, out of 2.5 million rows in my table, 'XX' shows up in the DevReadType column 12,000 times. Do you know if there is a way to do this delete using variables rather than specifying the exact instances that need to be deleted?